# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/code/manage.py'

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I was trying to run django app on docker container.
Followed steps mentioned at https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/
But after running the command `docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject composeexample .`
I facing error PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/code/manage.py'
I'm using centos 7. please help

```
[root@localhost docker-django]# docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject composeexample .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/startproject.py", line 33, in handle
    super(Command, self).handle('project', project_name, target, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/templates.py", line 154, in handle
    with open(new_path, 'wb') as new_file:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/code/manage.py'
```

Comment: try `sudo chmod -R 775 /code/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with SELinux enabled on centos 7. It worked [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-code-manage-py/3410/2).

Answer (score 0):

There is a pending upstream issue [issue 1842](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1842) and [issue 1936](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1936).

[PR 1843](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/1843) for the first one will get you somewhere but it's not ok long term or prod.

Please monitor them and you will get a correct answer