# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/manage.py'

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, django-admin

I am trying to run the following command in `docker-composer`, to start project with `django-admin`:

```
docker-compose run app sh -c "django-admin startproject app ."
```

This produces the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/startproject.py", line 20, in handle
    super().handle('project', project_name, target, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/templates.py", line 155, in handle
    with open(new_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as new_file:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/manage.py'
```

The Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
MAINTAINER anubrij chandra

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./app /app



RUN adduser -D dockuser
USER dockuser
```

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

I applied the solution suggested in [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606304/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-code-manage-py), but it didn't work.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your `dockerfile`, you are pointing to a new user `dockuser`.

```
RUN adduser -D dockuser
USER dockuser
```

Hence your container will start with user `dockuser` which does not seem to have proper permissions to run `/manage.py`.

You can either

- remove the above mentioned lines where you create and point to
  `dockuser`.

OR

- provide appropriate permissions to user `dockuser` using `chown` and `chmod` commands in your dockerfile for /manage.py file.

I have answered such similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56696962/6790948).

Comment: Removing the docker user solved my permission-denied issue in AWS EFS / Fargate

Answer (score 73):

## ubuntu 21.04

I got here searching for `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:` so i'll just leave this here.

**note:** the below answer doesn't work for multi user systems ... [see this answer instead for another possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70124863/2026508)

---

If you want to set it and forget it for 1 user, your own user ... here's what I have on my dev machine.

I didn't own the unix socket, so I chowned it. ( this got it working straight away )

```
sudo chown $(whoami):$(whoami) /var/run/docker.sock
```

Another, more permanent solution for your dev environment, is to modify the user ownership of the unix socket creation. This will give your user the ownership, so it'll stick between restarts:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/docker.socket
```

docker.socket:

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Socket for the API

[Socket]
ListenStream=/var/run/docker.sock
SocketMode=0660
SocketUser=YOUR_USERNAME_HERE
SocketGroup=docker

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Again another less hacky solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70124863/2026508

#### NOTE for WSL ( NevilleLusimba )

might also want to change directory/app ownership to docker

```
$ sudo chgrp -R docker /path/to/directory
```

and give read and write access to docker

```
$sudo chmod -R g+rw /path/to/directory
```

Worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS via WSL

Comment: Nothing else worked for me, thank you for listing this out!

Comment: 10 stars, solved my problem

Comment: Can't do this on a multi-user system. It's better just to add yourself to the *docker* user group

Comment: @Shōgun8 could potentially add multiple users to the `docker` group see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70124863/2026508 in lieu of making changes to the systemd sockets.target

Comment: @jmunsch - I'm not sure if you understood my comment. I suggested adding self to docker group because *you can't have multiple users chowning a file, as in `chown $(whoami)` *

Comment: @Shōgun8 i'll add a note

Comment: You might also want to change directory/app ownership to docker

$ sudo chgrp -R docker /path/to/directory

and give read and write access to docker
$sudo chmod -R g+rw /path/to/directory

Worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS via WSL

Comment: @NevilleLusimba Thanks! I'll add the note.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue and solved it by adding my user to the `docker` group:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)
```

Comment: Note: this will **not** take effect within your running session – you'll need to login afresh.

Answer (score 7):

add this to your `Dockerfile` after `RUN adduser -D dockuser`:

```
RUN chown dockuser:dockuser -R /app/
```

and why you `COPY`the files if you already mount them ?

if you want to keep the mount , you need to add `rw` persmission on the folder on the `HOST` system not on the `Container`

Comment: `Step 11/11 : RUN chown user:user -R /app/
 ---> Running in 4692ee51488d
chown: /app/: Operation not permitted
chown: /app/: Operation not permitted
The command '/bin/sh -c chown user:user -R /app/' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Comment: Yeah, CHOWNing the folder did the thing.

Comment: @PranKumarSarkar you've to do it before `USER user` line.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on mac this might work for you.

After 4 days of troubleshooting this error (and other strange errors) I found out that I needed to fix dockers permissions in my file system. To do this go to:

**System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy tab -> Full Disk Access  (on the left, somewhere in the list) -> Click on the + -> Docker application**

Terribly frustrating problem to debug, hope it helps.

Comment: This is absolutely important -- will likely be a huge problem for a lot of people.

Comment: How to do this on Ubuntu or Windows? I got the same error.

Comment: This deserves more upvotes. Really really saved my day. Thanks man!!!

Answer (score 1):

The Dockerfile that I was using was in the shared directory of my virtual machine (VirtualBox). Therefore, my issue was related to the default permission of this directory (UID=root, GID=vboxdf). I had to change it to my current user to properly run my container.

See https://superuser.com/a/640028/1655184 for a description on how to change the owner.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a WSL2 / Docker-Desktop setup issue on Windows.

What was missing was to explicitly enable the WSL distro: Docker Desktp Settings > Resources > WSL Integration > enable your distro

Then re-open WSL shell.

Before I could not even do `docker run hello-world` but also had a very similar error message as the OP when running docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

adding path to app like '/home/user/app:/app' in docker-compose instead of just '.:/app' resolved my problem

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu, just add sudo to your command and run as root to get the permissions.

`sudo docker-compose run app sh -c "django-admin startproject app ."`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar issue, the problem was I running docker-desktop. The solution was to exit docker-desktop.
Os: Ubuntu 20.04LTS

rebuild and re-run command after exiting.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me with Docker Desktop was adding the relevant project directory to the "virtual file shares", in the following way:

`Docker Desktop` -> `Settings` (Gear icon) -> `Resources` -> `File sharing` (sub-menu) -> add `<path>/<to>/<project-directory>` to the list `virtual file shares`.

Hope that helps!