# permission denied in docker-compose on linux

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

```
(base) a@a-ThinkPad-T440:~$ docker-compose version
bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose: Permission denied
```

I have big problem with docker-compose, I tried to upgrade `docker-compose` to `1.25` with curl but now I have no permission for docker-compose (I have linux ubuntu)

Comment: How did you upgrade `docker-compose` with `curl`? What command did you run?

Comment: How did you try to upgrade docker-compose? Does `/usr/bin/docker-compose --version` work?

Comment: I had a similar problem where I followed the Linux install steps but the auto-created `docker` group didn't gain permissions to execute docker-compose. For me this  fixed it (without opening it to any user): `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER` to add myself to docker group, `sudo chgrp docker /usr/local/bin/docker-compose` to give docker-compose to docker group, `sudo chmod 750 /usr/local/bin/docker-compose` to allow docker group users to execute it

Comment: This question is about "softeware tools primarily used by programmers" so maybe the Question Closing Police need to lighten up a bit

Answer (score 110, accepted):

As far as I can understand you are using docker's source to install docker-compose and you forgot the second step. [Source for complete installation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/).

As second step states. Apply executable permissions to the binary:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose;
```

In addition to the comments provided in the question

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER                  # to add myself to docker group
sudo chgrp docker /usr/local/bin/docker-compose     # to give docker-compose to docker group,
sudo chmod 750 /usr/local/bin/docker-compose   # to allow docker group users to execute it
```

You might want to try running `newgrp docker`

Comment: For unknown reasons I needed a restart before the above worked.

Comment: @shad0w_wa1k3r the updated docs I found tell you you need to either reboot or run `su - $USER` after making the group change. You could also log out then log in. This is very standard, any time you make a permissions change it isn't reflected until next login.

Comment: In my case I also had to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68464690/1266873

Comment: I found the instructions here https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

Comment: You might also want to restart the docker daemon when you create and add yourself to the docker group