# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/manage.py'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I run docker-compose command and get "PermissionDenied" error. I have used the same code about 2 month ago and it worked perfectly. I have searched internet and solutions didn't help much.

```
docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "django-admin startproject app ."
```

And it gives me an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/py/bin/django-admin", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/startproject.py", line 21, in handle
    super().handle('project', project_name, target, **options)
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/templates.py", line 160, in handle
    with open(new_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as new_file:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/manage.py'
```

My Dockerfile is :

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13
LABEL maintainer="Kananappdeveloper"

ENV PYHTONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY ./requirements.dev.txt /tmp/requirements.dev.txt
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

ARG DEV=false
RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    if [ $DEV = "true" ]; \
        then /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.dev.txt ; \
    fi && \
    rm -rf /tmp && \
    adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --no-create-home \
    django-user

ENV PATH="/py/bin:$PATH"

USER django-user
```

My OS is Ubuntu 22.04

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your issue looks very similar to

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56784492/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-manage-py

Have you tried these options?

Comment: That didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

Check the username of the creator of the folder `app` using the command `ll`.
Then find out the user id of the user.

Then create the user in Docker with that id using

```
adduser \
       -u $ \
       --disabled-password \
       --no-create-home \
       django-user
```

Then build docker.

Answer (score 0):

when you make docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - DEV=true
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app #here i forgot ":" but now 
    command: >
     sh -C "python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

on volumes dont forget colon `:`. I had similar problem and it fixed for me.